# Qt: save QPixmap to std::vector<unsigned char> - or convert QByteArray to std::vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted to convert a QPixmap to std::vector . For now I am doing the following

```
     QPixmap pixmap;
     QByteArray bytes;
     QBuffer buffer(&bytes);
     buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
     pixmap.save(&buffer, "JPG");
```

However I donot know how to convert `QbyteArray` to `std::vector<unsigned char>`

any suggestions ?

Comment: `std::vector<unsigned char> c(buffer.constData(), buffer.constData() + buffer.size())`

Comment: QBuffer does not have `constData()` could u you explain that please

Comment: Sorry, I mean `QByteArray` of course.

Comment: Could you put that as answer so I could mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record, as user @Lol4t0 didn't do it:

```
 std::vector<unsigned char> c(bytes.constData(), bytes.constData() + bytes.size());
```

Comment: @kleopatra Creates a vector with QPixmap's content. Therefore, it answered the question.

Comment: ahh .. then I misunderstood your _as user @Lol4t0 didn't do it_ (confused by the negation :-) Thanks for the clarification